# VirtualBox 5.1.22 on OSX 10.10.5 fail to start after install

Tags: virtualbox

I get the following error when starting from Terminal:

```
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxRT.dylib",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

And when I run vagrant I get:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "a8a8fac4-2c8d-4ad4-9ab6-1d200a742c90", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'bapresta16_default_1499355015641_13826' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I couldn't found any info about these errors anywhere.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
sudo chown root:admin /Applications
sudo chmod o-w /Applications
```

Run the lines in the Terminal.